# What does crawl-delay: 1 mean if it is interpreted as is?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, robots.txt

I have a problem of understanding what `crawl-delay: 1` means if it isn't ignored and actually being interpreted as is by a given web crawler.

[I understood from this answer by Stephen Ostermiller](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/127958/58733) that:

> With a crawl delay of `10` a crawler should:
>
> - Crawl a page A
> - Wait at least 10 seconds
> - Crawl page B
>
> That would mean that a crawler could crawl at most 6 pages per minute (60 seconds divided by 10); 360 pages per hour, or 8,640 pages per day.
>
> The smaller the crawl delay → the more crawling is allowed.

Well, from that I understand that, a crawling of up to one webpage per second and then a delay of a second will bring the crawling of 30 webpages per minute.

and yet, when corresponding in comments, I understood from Stephen it will be close to or near 60 crawlings ("fetches").

Well, `60 crawlings` or `at most 30` crawlings?

In other words,

**What does crawl-delay: 1 mean if it is interpreted as is?**

Comment: Why are you assuming 1 second crawling?   That is going to depend on the speed of your site and the speed of the network.     Are you trying to determine the most crawling that could happen (very fast page loads), or how limiting it could be for bots that want to go faster?  As I noted in the other question, that depends on how crawlers interpret when they have to wait from in any case.

Comment: `Why are you assuming 1 second crawling?` by principle. `Are you trying to determine the most crawling that could happen (very fast page loads), or how limiting it could be for bots that want to go faster?`  I try to understand what will happen when a crawler "respects" `crawl-delay: 1` as is; nothing more (although it is clear to me that there could be some "disrespects" or biases as you have explained).

Answer (score 3):

The exact interpretation of crawl delay is not specified anywhere.  Crawlers could reasonably interpret it in two ways:

1. They have to wait between starting requests
2. They have to wait between the end of one request and the start of the next

For example, here how a crawler might fetch three pages according to rule #1

```
0         1         2         3  seconds
|*page1**          
|         |*page2*********
|         |         |*page3*
```

And here is how the same fetch might look under rule #2

```
0         1         2         3         4         5  seconds
|*page1**          
|         |        **page2********
|         |         |         |         |   **page3*
```

Both of the crawlers are obeying some interpretation of the directive, but the first may have overlapping requests and the second may take a lot longer to crawl.

Wikipedia notes this in the [crawl-delay section of their robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Crawl-delay_directive) article.  It says that Bingbot obeys interpretation #1 and Yandexbot obeys interpretation #2.

With a crawl delay of `1`, the fastest a crawler observing crawl delay could hit your site would be 60 times per minute.  Any crawler (eg Bingbot) observing rule #1 might hit this speed.

If a bot is observing rule #2, it won't be able to crawl as quickly.    The number of requests in a time period will depend on how quickly your site can deliver pages (including network transmission time) to that crawler.  For:

- Time `t` in seconds,
- Crawl delay `cd` in seconds
- Average page speed `aps` in seconds

the formula for the average number of pages that can be fetched in a time period is:

```
t / ( cd + aps)
```

So if you have a crawl delay of `1` and it takes on average a second to serve a page on your site, here is how the major search engines will behave:

- Googlebot ignores the crawl delay and fetches as many pages as it wants as long it it doesn't look like your site is slowing down because of it.
- Bingbot will fetch at most sixty pages in a minute.
- Yandexbot will fetch at most thirty pages in a minute.

It is also worth noting that the crawl-delay puts a maximum cap on the number of pages crawled.   Crawlers may choose to crawl fewer page if they desire.

Comment: Is there any way to simplify the answer? I think I misunderstood what is going on; I understand `crawl-delay` command can be ignored or interpreted but that is not what I am asking about; I only mean to ask about what happens when `crawl-delay: 1` does get "respected" fully (i.e not ignored or interpreted but is executed as is).

Comment: The simple answer is "it depends."   "As is" is open to interpretation.

Comment: Stephen - I am sorry, I am still confused about the 30-60 range of seconds issue if we assume that no special "interpretation" is done and a crawler works with a `crawl-delay: 1` directive "as is".

Comment: The answer is still "it depends."  Some crawlers may crawl 60 pages per minute with a crawl delay of 1.   Some crawlers will ignore the directive.  Other crawlers will limit themselves further basing the delay on the time between page fetches.

Comment: I am sorry, your last comment made me more confused than I was before regarding this specific matter of `crawl-delay: 1`.

Comment: If you want to edit or try a different explanation, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hello? I admit i'm having a hard time understanding what I allege as ignoring me.

Comment: I'm not sure how I  can be clearer.   What part is confusing you?

Comment: Well, let's assume that `crawl-delay: 1` is interpreted as is --- one fetch, one second stop, one fetch, one second stop and so forth ------ how do we get a range of 30-60 seconds instead just saying "yes it's 30 seconds"?

Comment: Does that mean fetch a page, finish that fetch, stop for one second?  Or does it mean Start a fetch, stop for one second, start the next fetch whether or not the first one completed?

Comment: It means telling the bot `start to fetch, stop to fetch, and then wait one second`; if the bot indeed waits one second after each start and finish, then I understand we get a range of about 15-30 seconds, not of 30-60 seconds; am I missing something?...

Comment: You can't tell the bot to interpret it that way.  Some bots do and some don't.   If that is how the bots do it then the average fetches per minute will use the formula I put in the answer.

Comment: I understand I don't, but I ask about a mode in which a bot does indeed interpret it this way; hence I assume 15-30 seconds rage and not 30-60 seconds as I understand you have postulated; I didn't understand the formula; perhaps I need to read again but all I am asking is why you presented 30-60 seconds range instead the more plausible (if `1` delay is respected) 15-30 seconds range...

Comment: Some crawlers will actually crawl 60 URLs in a minute with a crawl delay of 1 second, regardless of how long your server takes to serve the pages.

Comment: But Stephen --- how can this be ------ in case they do indeed "respect" the delay of `1` second?...

Comment: Because they start new requests exactly every 1 second.

Comment: So I miss the point of the entire delay if a delay of 1 second doesn't cut the amount of fetches **at least** in half...

Comment: No, that isn't the whole point.   The point is that crawlers delay 1 second.    Different crawlers implement that delay differently.  They can do so because when the delay should happen is not specified in any documentation about crawl delay.

Comment: You say that a crawler can do 60 fetches in one second, wait one second, then do 60 more fetches IN SOME CASES? Well, if so, I think this should be clearly explained in the answer, which would be historical (and in the future maybe also legendary).

Comment: No.  I'm saying the crawler can start a request exactly every second, on the second.  If the crawl delay were `2`, the crawler could start a crawl every other second.     Some crawlers delay between the start of requests.  They would consider the time taken to perform the request as part of that delay, not in addition to the delay.

Comment: Let me ask you a question to see if you understand.  The crawl delay is set to 10.  Say that the current time (hours:mins:secs) is 2:25:10.    A crawler requests a document and that request takes 5 seconds.  At what time is the crawler next allowed to make a request for each of the two ways they could interpret the rules around crawl-delay?

Comment: Well, I admit, I don't know at what time.

Comment: Well what time would you expect based on your understanding of crawl-delay?

Comment: 15-30 seconds because as I understand, and here might be the problem --- a fetch of a second, is only of one page.

Comment: Well, I formally give up with this matter → I will tell the world that ATMO, it will be about 15-30 seconds while you will tell the world it will be about 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Crawl-delay is used to stop bot from crawling web pages or website very frequently. However, it should be used when your website have number of pages and is a big size website. Crawl-delay can be used in social bookmarking sites, sites like twitter, facebook etc. which are very frequently updated.

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Crawl-delay: 120
```

Its means is that Googlebot should crawl webpages in delay of 120 second not frequently.

Comment: Googlebot doesn't support the crawl-delay directive.  See [“Crawl-delay” rule ignored by googlebot](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106546/crawl-delay-rule-ignored-by-googlebot).   It is an optional extenson to robots.txt.   Googlebot is one of the bots that doesn't use it.

Comment: It’s important to say that the Google bot does not take into consideration the crawl-delay setting. That is why you should not worry that such a directive can influence your Google standings and you can safely use it, in case there are other aggressive bots you want to stop. It is highly unlikely to experience issues due to Google bot crawling, but if you want to lower its crawl-rate you can do this only from the Google Search Console